# Parameter is not valid - PictureBox em C#

Tags: c#, syntax-error, picturebox

Estou a fazer um visualizador de ficheiros TIFF em VisualStudio 2017, na linguagem C#. 
Consigo abrir o ficheiro TIFF, se for multipage vai separá-lo por páginas e consigo mostrar cada página e navegar por elas. O meu problema é quando vou abrir outro TIFF.

Eu fecho o ficheiro e quando abro outro, aparece-me o erro

> Parameter is not valid.

na linha em que torno visível a `PictureBox`. 
Podiam me dizer o que está de errado no meu código ou se devo fazer as coisas de outra maneira? Obrigada desde já.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    pbtiff.Hide();  
    OpenFileDialog dialogo = new OpenFileDialog();  
    dialogo.Title = "Search files";   
    dialogo.InitialDirectory = @"E:\";   
    dialogo.Filter = "PDF Files(.pdf)|*.pdf|Image Files (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.tiff,.tif) |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*tiff;*tif";   
    DialogResult answer = dialogo.ShowDialog();  
    if (answer == DialogResult.OK)  
    {  
        string fullPath = dialogo.FileName;   
        openFile = fullPath;  
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ficheiroaberto, FileMode.Open))  
        {  
            type = Path.GetExtension(caminhoCompleto);  
            if (type == ".tif" || type == ".tiff")  
            {  
                up.Visible = true;  
                up.Enabled = false;  
                down.Visible = true;  
                pbtiff.Show(); //-> o erro está nesta linha, quando a abro pela segunda vez
                if (pbtiff.Image != null)  
                {  
                    pbtiff.Image.Dispose();  
                }  
                pbtiff.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream);  
                SplitTiffFinal(fileStream);  
                filestiff = GetFilesFinal();  
                up.Visible = true;  
                up.Enabled = false;  
                down.Visible = true;  
             }  
         }  
     }  
 }
```

E o código do meu botão de fechar:

```
private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pbtiff.Image != null)
    {
            pbtiff.Image.Dispose();
            pbtiff.InitialImage = null;
            pbtiff.Hide();
            up.Visible = false;
            down.Visible = false;
            filestiff.Clear();
            idx = 0;
            type = "";

            DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo(@"temporarioviewer");
            DeletingFiles(path); 
    }
    else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Deve abrir um ficheiro primeiro para poder fechá-lo.", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sofia, bom dia! Você não teria que dar dispose toda vez ao invés de clear e depois começar o processo novamente?

Comment: @Sofia, o que é esse "IF" sem parâmetros?

Comment: @Fabioln tem razão, eu é que me enganei a copiar e a editar o código.. Aquele IF estava a mais! Erro meu

Comment: @AngeloSimonato o "clear" é de um `List<string>`, não da PictureBox. Mas colocaria o dispose quando carregava no botão para abrir um TIFF?

Comment: @SofiaRodrigues, o dispose seria pra descartar o objeto, ai você preencheria ele novamente como fez na primeira rodada. Estou olhando pra linha que deu o erro e que você sinalizou.

Comment: @AngeloSimonato mas eu já tenho um "IF" para fazer dispose caso a PictureBox tenha uma imagem, e um dispose quando fecho o ficheiro... Onde é que teria que colocar outro dispose, se eu já tenho um em casa evento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é porque estás a chamar o método `Show()` depois de fazer `Dispose()` na propriedade Image da picturebox (através do botão de fechar).

Não sei explicar o que causa o erro internamente, mas se chamares o `Show()` depois de inserires uma nova imagem já não vais ter esse problema:

```
if (pbtiff.Image != null)  
{  
    pbtiff.Image.Dispose();  
}  
pbtiff.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream);
pbtiff.Show(); //-> o erro está nesta linha, quando a abro pela segunda vez
```

Comment: Era mesmo isso, foi um erro meu muito despistado... Obrigada pela ajuda!